# OS dependent rules in Bazel

Tags: bazel

I use Bazel as build system. I have a `cc_library` rule working well on Linux. I would like my code to compile on Windows where some options may be different. For example, `'-std=c++14'` / `'/std:c++14'`, or `"-lpthread"`.

```
cc_library(
        name = "name",
        hdrs = ["file.hpp"],
        srcs = ["file.cpp"],
        copts = ['-std=c++14'] # '/std:c++14' for Windows
        linkopts = ["-lpthread"],
        visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

What is the bazelistic way to handle this? I have seen [Platforms](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/platforms-intro.html#should-i-use-platforms) but it seems overkill and I don't understand if it is meant for this.

Comment: Add a `.bazelrc` to your project. Add the lines `build:vs2019 --cxxopt=/std:c++14` and  `build:gcc --cxxopt=-std=c++14` - build your code  `bazel build --config=msvc //...` or `bazel build --config=gcc //...`. I am really unhappy that his question was closed...

Comment: I closed the question because I managed to get the desired behavior with the link provided. However, the solution you posted seems better for global compilation options such as -std